# What's the purpose of bookmarks in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I read about bookmarks in mercurial, every source states that it's like git branching, that the bookmark gets updated uppon every commit, but I really don't understand what's its purpose. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BookmarksExtension):

> Bookmarks are references to commits that are automatically updated
>   when new commits are made. If you do hg bookmark feature the feature
>   bookmark refers to the current changeset. As you work and commit
>   changes the bookmark will move forward with every commit you do. The
>   bookmark will always point to the latest revision in your line of
>   work. Since bookmarks are automatically updated when committing to the
>   changeset they are pointing to, they are especially useful to keep
>   track of different heads. They can therefore be used for trying out
>   new features or pulling changes that have yet to be reviewed.

I also suggest reading [this article](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-bookmarks) for an overview of the various ways to branch in Mercurial.

I suggest not taking bookmarks and trying to find a use for them, but rather finding a process you find natural to use in your team and then finding how Mercurial best handles branches in the context of that process, be it with bookmarks or cloning or what have you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding just a few minor details, to the excellent points of Mihai Danila:

Bookmarks are, in a few words, a lot like: *"movable tags without a permanent movement log"*.

There are various features built on top of the 'movable tag' property, like merging of bookmarks from other clones, automatic movement of the bookmark as you commit on top of it, etc. But the basic idea is pretty much just that. A symbolic name that you can attach to a changeset, much like a 'tag', but one that can move arbitrarily forward or backward in history as required.

You can definitely built a branching scheme on top of bookmarks. In fact, Mercurial itself has adopted the names 'crew' and 'crew-stable' for two bookmarks that the development team uses to coordinate Mercurial's own development. But you don't *have* to.

I agree 100% with what Mihai wrote: "Don't take bookmarks and try to find a use for them, but rather find a process you find natural to use in your team and then find out how Mercurial best handles branches in the context of that process, be it with bookmarks or cloning or what have you".